# VB Sending keystrokes to a minimized window/app

Tags: vb.net

im a complet noob in vb . i have been trying to figure out how to send keystrokes back to my own application , while minimized/ Or focused on an other window.
i think i need to use PostMessageA . i read about it on forums. But its like chinese for me.
my goal is to run these little programs by the 100's on 1 pc. and they just press a key in their own application , over and over.
can someone help me out please.
thanks

i was thinking something like this

```
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long,  ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Const WM_CHAR As Long = &H102
```

---

```
PostMessage("notepad", WM_CHAR, "T", 1)
```

as a test. what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

A few things, for one you have found your code in a VB6 Forum. The size of integers has changed since then. A `Long` in VB6 is equivalant to an `Integer` in VB.Net([see this Msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f5ztkz3.aspx)). The second issue is that you are supplying a `String` to `PostMessage` where it is expecting the handle to your window. I would suggest that you look at this CodeProject article about how to [Send strings to another application by using Windows messages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19740/Send-strings-to-another-application-by-using-Windo)

Your `PostMessage` declaration should look like this.

```
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: its a bit of help . but like i said im pretty new to vb.
it all seems overly complicated, to just do a keystroke , while minimized or not focused.  =/

Comment: @BobGratton Using the windows api to send messages between windows is an advanced topic. That is the reason that I gave you the link, try downloading the source and play with it. I would agree that the article may be overkill but it does work.

Comment: i was able to make it work Thanks you!1 problem the Box i am writting in has a js character counter, that only counts on focus to the textarea.the submit button only "apears" if there is text in the box,  i am putting text in the box, but i am not focusing on it so the Js counter isnt counting em . if i manually click on the box after my program wrote in it, its fine  .i can then submit. i dont think emulating a mouse click  on the box when minimized would change it.anyone got ideas how to get the JS character counter to count the characters without having to focus on the textarea  ? :) thanks

Comment: @BobGratton You would be better served asking this as a new question it will be more likely to get noticed.

Comment: hey mark , u seem to know your stuff. Quick question: i wish to open my program(vb) that contains a webbrowser . But for Each instance of my program i start . i would like a new session. Example, i could logon facebook different accounts on each. Any idea?

Comment: @BobGratton I really haven't played with the Webbrowswer control, but if you are opening seperate instances they will each have there own Webbrowser control and you should have no problem logging in to different sites. I would probably pass the unique information as a command line argument to your program.

Comment: @BobGratton First of all you should be asking this as a new question. but try something like this `Dim address As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri(address))`

Comment: cool thanks ill work on that  :) its much quicker asking someone who knows their stuff   ! Thanks alot gona work on that.
Ps: they didnt have their own instances. they were all sharing the same cookies :( thats why i was asking this. even tho i was naming them different processes

Comment: @BobGratton Good, I am more of a process control programmer not a web programmer so if my answer helped I am glad